# Unexpected token D in json?

Tags: javascript

I need to get csv data from an url, which returns a string. When I call `res.json()` it throws an error that unexpected token D in json at position 0 (the first letter of the string). Why? The response is exactly what I want, and I just want to get it.

```js
fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1718/I1.csv")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: By the extension, .csv, you're not loading JSON data but CSV data. You'll have to read it as text (`res.text()`) and parse from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are requesting a csv file so it's not a json. Use res.text() to retrieve the text instead.